# Vs code not allowing me to choose Python 3.7.3 as interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip

It asked that I need to select a Python interpreter, with a triangle and an exclamation mark next to it, whenever I choose Python 3.7.3 it just keeps saying select python interpreter, whereas when I choose Python 3.8.2 it works but running a program with a library like matplotlib, it says module not find, I tried installing it, but it said requirements already satisfied, (I think pip3 installs it only on Python 3.7.3), so I uninstalled, deleted the .vscode file, everything I could, but nothing worked. I do use VS code on a Windows PC with the accounts linked using Github, and I share Dropbox with them (only to share the coding files and projects).

```
Os = MacOs

VS code Version = 1.56.2 (universal)

Python 3.7.3 is stored in usr/local/bin/python3, whereas Python 3.8.2 is stored in usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and enter Preferences: Open User Settings. Then set python.pythonPath, which is in the Python extension section of User Settings, with the appropriate interpreter.

Or else you can change it from status bar which locate bottom left corner, when you open any python code.

Comment: That is what I am saying, whenever I went to settings.json or tried changing it from the bottom left, it didn't change for some odd reason. Any reason why?

Comment: ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python             Try this

Answer (score 0):

For Matplotlib you can do :

```
`python3.8 -m pip install matplotlib`
```

Comment: I tried it, it says "-bash: python3.8.2: command not found".

Comment: @Eletrix does the python shell open with              'python3.8'? What method did you use to install python ?

Comment: No, when I typed `python3.8 -m pip install matplotlib` into the terminal, that is what it returned.

Answer (score -1):

**First Problem**: asking you to select the interpreter after you choose Python 3.7.3.

It looks like the environment has been damaged, But the caches still keep the early information falsely. You can follow the path of the Python 3.7.3 location to check whether you can find the python.exe(windows) file.

**Second Problem**: unable to install the matplotlib package.

You can check which pip you are using through 'pip --version' command first. If you have not installed the pip in Python 3.8.2(you can not find pip.exe in the python.exe folder [windows]), you can install it through `python get-pip.py`(macos) command to install it.